# "Event is not defined" in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, events, firefox, ember.js

HTML Code which calls a function on a level select event. This code is written in Ember framework.

```
{{ action "onLevelSelect" this on="change" target= "view"}}
```

Javascript function which is called by triggering this event:

```
onLevelSelect : function(event) {
    var getSelectedLevel = event.target.selectedOptions[0].label;   // error line

    /*rest of the code goes below*/
}
```

When it comes to "error line", i m getting this error.

> `"ReferenceError: event is not defined".`

I have tried window.event and event.which and i also tried by sending event explicitly to the function `"onLevelSelect"`.

Comment: That error looks impossible there. It'd be more like *can't ready property of undefined*.

Comment: did u try event = event || window.event ?

Comment: I tried event || window.event. But it didn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem but forgot to update.
The Solution is

Firefox doesn't support the ember handlebar syntax to handle events like `Click`, `Change` etc. But it works in Chrome. So, I used jQuery functions to handle these events like `click(event){}`, `change(event){}`, etc.(we can also use HTML functions like `onClick()`, `onChange()`) .

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is correct. **Ember does not pass the event object, if you use the action helper.** Can you show more of your code of view and template? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: But how it works in Chrome if Ember doesn't pass the event object? Can you explain in more detail way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed this by using `onclick={{action ...}}` instead of just `{{action ...}}` in the handlebars.. I have also seen this documented elsewhere. Using the action helper by itself doesn't pass the event object. However using onclick does.

So basically change your code to this:

```
onclick={{ action "onLevelSelect" this on="change" target= "view"}}
```

Comment: Also make sure that you have event in the function definition which above it appears you do.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox global `window.event` is not accessible inside onclick function callback. so you should not rely on this.
`<input {{action 'onLevelSelect'}} value="test" />` - here you will not receive `event` object in `onLevelSelect` method.

But in the below, you will receive `event` object as the last argument,

```
<input onchnage={{action 'onLevelSelect'}} value="test" />
```

I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736820/5771666) detailed