# How can we get the original event in ember's action

Tags: ember.js

I'm updating a personal project where I used the ember.js version 0.9.x.

So a new version was released and I have a problem related with ember action.

I have the following html code:

```
<li><a href="#" id="startApp" {{action activateView target="view"}}> Home</a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>
```

where, when I click its call this function activateView:

```
activateView: function(event, context) {
   console.log(event);              
}
```

but the event and the context are undefined. I've already tried this.context and it returns undefined.

The main idea its obtain the id of the link when the user click.

I know about routes and the handlebar helper link to, but I really need that id for other things,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The event is not passed using the action helper.  If you really want the event object, you need to define a view and use the `click` event:

```
App.MyLink = Em.View.extend({
  click: function(e) {
  }
});
```

and then:

```
<li>{{view App.MyLink}}</li>
```

but requiring access to the dom event is a rare case, because you can pass arguments to `{{action}}`.  In your case:

```
<li><a href="#" id="startApp" {{action activateView "startApp" target="view"}}> Home</a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>
```

and in the event:

```
activateView: function(id) {
  console.log(id);              
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It was hours to try resolve this and in the end the solution its very simple.

Comment: There's more to an event than just the DOM element.  I understand that it's a better practice to not access the event in an action, or to setup my own custom handler if I really need to.  But is there some back door to access the event anyway?  Basically no one has actually answered the OP's question.

Comment: Ember.View is now deprecated. Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: @KevinBullaughey Ember.Component

Answer (score 19):

In Ember 2...

Inside your action you always have access to the Javascript `event` object which has the DOM element e.g.

```
actions: {
    myAction() {
        console.log(event.target) // prints the DOM node reference
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this doesn't seem to work in Firefox. I get an error stating: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/6fra6cL4/

Comment: Is this mentioned anywhere in the Ember docs? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: In Ember 3 as well

Comment: Works in Ember 3.13 on all major browsers

Comment: However have in mind that it is a) not an Ember feature and b) not recommended feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can receive `event` object in actions,

1.If you are using component, then you can define any of this list of event names in component and that is designed to receive native event object. eg., `{{my-button model=model}}`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
 click(event){
  //oncliking on this componen will trigger this function
  return true; //to bubble this event up
 }
})
```

2.If you are using html tag like button then you need to assign a (closure) action to an inline event handler.

```
{{#each item as |model|}}
      <button onclick={{action 'toggle' model}}>{{model.title}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

In actions hash toggle function will always receive native browser event object as the last argument.

```
actions:{
 toggle(model,event){

 }
}
```

In the below format, action toggle will not receive `event` object,

- `<button {{action 'toggle'}}>{{model.title}}</button>`
- Input helpers such as `{{input key-press="toggle"` and `{{text-area key-press="toggle"`

Explained really well in ember guide https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/handling-events/#toc_sending-actions

Comment: This should be the correct answer for the latest Ember versions at least

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the id into your function like so to have it accessible in the view, you can pass along what ever you want, but in your example this should do it

**html**

```
<li><a href="#" id="startApp" {{action activateView "startApp" target="view"}}> Home</a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>
```

then you have access to the id or what ever you passed in, in the view

**js**

```
...
activateView: function(data){
  console.log(data); // should be the ID "startApp"
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It was hours to try resolve this and in the end the solution its very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just use event handler directly.

Reference: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1684

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, but here is [the relevant documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/#toc_the-on-modifier) using Ember Octane.

`The callback function will receive the event as its first argument:`

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  @action
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```