# How do I capture keyPress events on an item in a list with ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, accessibility

I'm trying to improve the accessibility of the applications I write. I'm also learning more about ember. As an exercise, I'm working with the [ember-js todoMVC demo app](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/) ([code for the app is here](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs)) to add features that assist users of screen readers.

One thing I'd like to learn how to do is trigger editing of a todo item from the keyboard. The `<label>` element that holds the `title` of the item could be focused and then go into edit mode with a press of the Enter/Return key. In the demo, only a double-click on the `<label>` will open the item for editing. This behavior is handled by an `action` helper, which I understand is used specifically for making elements clickable. Here's the part of the template in question. I've elided features of the code to remove unrelated logic:

```
{{#each itemController="todo"}}
  <li ... >
    ...
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
    ...
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

"Don't use the `action` helper" would seem to be the place to start. But what's the best way to handle each item now?

As the `itemController="todo"` in the `each` helper denotes, there is a `TodoController` (which extends `ObjectController`) that defines an `editTodo` function. I'd like to have a keyPress event trigger that function. (For now, we can disregard the inspection of the event to capture only the Enter/Retrun key.)

I've added `tabindex="0"` to the label element, and it appears I can focus it with my keyboard. I've tried adding a `keyPress` function to the `TodoController`'s `actions` hash, but it is not triggered when I press keys. I think this is because there isn't really a `View` for each item--the `ArrayController` for the todos and the template seem to be handling the display of the todo items between themselves.

I've done a lot of reading today, and it seems like I may need to specify a `View` for each item, possibly using a `ContainerView` and specifying its `itemViewClass` property, so that I can focus the view when it's inserted. But the examples for this on the ember site don't use the `each` helper: they have lower-level mechanisms for adding the rendered view that I suspect are not current best practice.

I suspect there's more than one way to do this, but I'm still too new to ember to figure it out. I think that figuring out this problem will illuminate a lot about the framework.

What would you do to add the keyPress support for editing to the demo?

Comment: You can extend the built-in helpers to accomplish your goal: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views You want to put your event-driven actions into an extension of any helper type you're using.

Comment: I should have also said that you can access the current controller from within a view with `this.get('controller')` or even the parent controller. This will give you access to what you need in the item controller.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte My newb-ness is showing, but I'm not sure how to extend a helper as you suggest. I know [you can capture a browser event in a view with a method named for the event type](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_method-implementation). This makes me think a view with a `keyPress` method would work well. How should I introduce an explicit view here? It seems that helpers can insert a view (or you can use the `view` helper itself). Sorry to be obtuse, but would you be able to point me to more information or examples?

Comment: Yep, you are on the right track there. A view is really just responsible for rendering a model, so it is only logical that it would have access to it (in your case, you want to generate a view for each looped model in your todo collection). Try `App.MyText = Ember.TextField.extend({})` and put your keypress action handler in there. Inside of your action, try, `console.log(this.get('controller.content'));` Hopefully that illuminates how a view and a controller can interact. You can also create your own custom components, but start with the helper extension to get an idea of how this all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Oliver and @MatthewBlancarte for pointing me in the right direction. I ultimately swapped out the `action` helper for a `view` helper that wraps the code for the label. [The whole diff is available on github](https://github.com/goodmike/AccessibleToDoApp/commit/02b219a7ec0d7a915a9770f63fcf0a4c9357e270).

I only needed specific behavior on the `label`, not the whole `li` or on the `input` field that replaces the label. I was pleased to discover that a View does not need a template: I can just write one that adds the behavior I want and then put the markup in the existing template for the Todos. Here's what that looked like:

```
- <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
+ {{#view "Todos.TodoLabelView"}}
+  <label tabindex="0">{{title}}</label>
{{/view}}
```

Then I could add the keyPress behavior I wanted on my new `TodoLabelView`:

```
Todos.TodoLabelView = Ember.View.extend({
  keyPress: function(ev) { 
    if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
      this.get("controller").send("editTodo");
    }
  },
  doubleClick: function() {
    this.get("controller").send("editTodo");
  },
});
```

This preserves the edit-on-double-click behavior with a separate handler.

Finally, I noticed that the [Enter] key press was being applied to the text field after it was rendered, which immediately closed the field and returned the label to the DOM. I tried returning `false` from my `keyPress` method as well as `Event#stopPropagation`. I even put the call to the controller's `editTodo` method on a timeout. No good.

I had to remove the `insert-newline="acceptChanges"` from the custom `edit-todo` handler and take care of an [Enter] keypress in the `EditTodoView`:

```
doubleClick: function() {
  this.get("controller").send("editTodo");
}
```

I'd love to hear opinions on my solution, especially if there's a much easier way or if I overlooked something important.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to change the `on="click"` event binding to `on="keyPress"`. You can find a list of supported events here:

> http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names

As you already mentioned you have to use the tabindex *hack* at the label element. But it looks like labels are not tabindexable in Chrome - Firefox and IE are fine.

```
{{#each itemController="todo"}}
  <li ... >
    ...
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label {{action "editTodo" on="keyPress"}}>{{title}}</label>
    ...
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Oliver. Changing the `on` attribute to `keyPress` does indeed make `editTodo` fire when I press a key while the label is focused.

However, no arguments are passed to the `editTodo` function, so there's no way to inspect the event to find out _which_ key was pressed. I know I said we could disregard the need to id the Enter/Retrun key, but now it's necessary.

It seems the `action` helper is not a way to register callbacks but rather acts as a callback handler: on an event, it fires the function. You can pass arguments in the helper, but there's no way to access the event there.

Comment: That's what view are for: *When you need sophisticated handling of user events*. There is also a SO question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499742/how-can-we-get-the-orginal-event-in-embers-action