# Event delegation and the global `event` object in Ember action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Today I've learned a bit about the [event delegation](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/Application) in Ember. The whole thing is exactly what I'd like to use in my code. There is a small problem though. When I migrate from

```
<div ondragend={{action "dragEnd"}}></div>
```

to

```
<div {{action "dragEnd" on="dragEnd"}}></div>
```

then I can't get the `event` parameter in my action method anymore and the thing is that I need it to get access to `event.clientX/Y`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39030071/467851) mentiones that it's possible to simply remove the parameter `event` and use it "globally" like this

```
...
actions: {
  dragEnd() {
    event.blahblah...
  }
}
```

So, I've got some questions regarding this technique:

1. Can anyone tell me how legal is it? It's not documented anywhere.
2. Do I understand correctly that in the case I use the closured action (`<div ondragend={{action "dragEnd"}}></div>`) it won't use the event delegation, i.e. it will attach the event handler to that `div` and not the `body` like it does according to the [doc](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.11/classes/Application) if I use this pattern (`<div {{action "dragEnd" on="dragEnd"}}></div>`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First why would you migrate to `{{action "dragEnd" on="dragEnd"}}`?
Thats the oldest style of ember actions and you shouldnt use them.
Use `ondragend={{action "dragEnd"}}` or better `{{on "dragEnd" this.dragEnd}}` when using a new action decorated with `@action`.
If you have your action in the `actions` hash use `{{on "dragEnd" (action "dragEnd")}}`.

and while [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is a browser feature I woudlnt use it! Reference to MDN:

> You should avoid using this property in new code

2. is correct. basically:

   - the `{{action` *modifier* (used without `=` before the `{{action`) will not attach any native event handlers, but waits for the event to bubble up to `body` where the event must already be registered (ember does this for a preset list of events) and then use a ember internal handling mechanism to trigger your action.
     This is basically from the old days, you should migrate *away* from it.
   - when you do `eventname={{action` you use the `{{action` *helper*. While it has the same name as the modifier it is not the same thing at all. The `{{action` helper just finds the action in the `actions` hash on your class, creates a bound action with maybe passed parameters and binds it to the correct `this`. Then this resulting action is assigned to the `eventname` *property* of the HTML DOM Element.
     This was a long time a very common way to do things, but never the officially preferred one. However its still a pretty good way to do things. The primary downside is that you cant add multiple actions to the same event. so `onclick={{action "foo}} onclick={{action "bar}}` on the same Element wont work.
   - the new `{{on` *modifier* is the new way to go with ember octane. It basically runs `addEventListener`. This allows to add multiple handlers as the `{{action` modifier does, but uses far less ember magic and directly adds the event to the DOM Element, not using any strange magic with custom event delegation. However it does not do any action lookup. So the second parameter directly needs to be a bound function that can be passed to `addEventListener`. For ember octane you would define the action directly on the class and add the `@action` decorator to it, which will basically create a bound function with the correct `this` context (it also adds the function to the `actions` hash to add compatibility with the `{{action` modifier and helper). For classic style actions you can use the `{{action` *helper* to look up the action and then pass it to the `{{on` modifier. Then you basically result in `{{on "click" (action "myAction")}}`.

So what to do:

- try to avoid `<button {{action "myAction" on="click"}}>` whenever possible. migrate *away* from it.
- when using classic style components/classes with `Component.extend({` use `<button onclick={{action "myAction}}>` or `<button {{on "click" (action "myAction")}}>`.
- when using native classes and/or glimmer components and you have your action decorated with the `@action` decorator use `<button {{on "click" this.myAction}}>`.

Comment: Oh, what an insightful answer! Could you tell me anything about performance side of things? Cause I have lots of elements I need to bind an event to and I thought that using this event delegation where I put a handler on a body would help me. And there is also the possibility to create an action handler in a component definition. Is it also anything to avoid?

Comment: yes, I would avoid action handlers in components! And the performance is not really a problem. It was years ago, but in all current browsers its not a problem to have many event handlers. If you have like a huge list this itself is a performance problem, no matter if you attach events or not. In this case consider [vertical-collection](https://github.com/html-next/vertical-collection).